# AWS.Route53.listResourceRecordSets(): no errors, empty data object in callback

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

sorry, maybe this is a very simple question, but I couldn't found the reason why it doesn't work as described in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Route53.html#listResourceRecordSets-property).

I use AWS JavaScript SDK with ExpressJS server and trying to get one DNS record from AWS. AWS.credentials will be taken from shared file. Everything works fine from console:

```
> aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXXXXXXXX --start-record-name test.example.net. --start-record-type TXT --max-items 1
```

returns valid record object. But JS AWS request:

```
new AWS.Route53({}).listResourceRecordSets({
      HostedZoneId: 'XXXXXXXX',
      StartRecordName: 'test.example.net.',
      StartRecordType: 'TXT',
      MaxItems: '1'
  }, function (error, data) {
      if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          callback({error: error})
      } else {
          callback(data); //<--- empty data object
      }
 });
```

will be resolved with no error but with empty data object (I expect deserialized response there, as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Route53.html#listResourceRecordSets-property)). In the network tab I can see that HTTP response returns 200 OK and contains valid xml data. What am I doing wrong and why no response data will be transferred to data object?

Any help is very appreciated!

UPDATE: I'm using NodeJS v5.1.0 + ExpressJS v4.13.3. Could it be that this version of Node is incompatible with AWS lib? (I didn't find the information about required Node version on the AWS site)

Comment: If you are getting a response back that has data and you can see it in your network tab, this is not an issue with the API. This is an issue with your scope in JavaScript. Instead of doing the callback in your code, just try doing a log to the console of your data object. If you see the response you expect, you can verify 100% that you have a scope problem.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I make breakpoint in the mentioned line callback(data) and checking data variable. It is an empty js object with prototype property only. I can also examine this context, which is  AWS response object. I can see there, that the http response body buffer length is 0. So at the point when the callback was fired, no data accessible. Looks like promise was resolved too early. But the docs says that I must call this method in exactly this way. :-/

Comment: That data object is only null if an error occurs. You have the callback function defined correctly, so I still think this is a scope issue. Instead of adding a breakpoint, replace ```callback(data)``` with ```console.log(data)```. That will tell you for sure. I am afraid the breakpoint is breaking outside the callback and that is why your inspection is showing no data. Humor me one more time and try this out!

Comment: He-he, I did it. As expected,  I've got the same info in the Node Inspector console: `Object: {__proto__: Object}` and in the server console just {}. Otherwise it would be crazy, that Node Inspector, I use for debugging, destroys scope vars and doesn't allow to inspect objects in place.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [similar issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/793) on aws-sdk home at github, this issue is caused by Node Inspector. So in my case it was the Node Inspector v0.12.3. It really destroyed data object. If I switch off Node Inspector in the Gruntfile, everything works es expected. This was fixed in the last version of the module (v0.12.5 at a time of writing).

**Solution:** update Node Inspector to latest version.